# Calling UIViewController from a JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to call a UIViewController from a JavaScript function within my project. I have been asked to make s some changes to this app, where I need to call a new UIViewController. I have found where I can call JavaScript functions, but I need to go the other way and open a UIViewController with some text on it. Does anyone have a sample of how to do this with the Xcode project code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For simple calls I would use [JSBridge](http://code.google.com/p/jsbridge-to-cocoa/). This requires to modify your javascript side with adding one JSBridge.js header file. I've tested it and it works.

The general idea is that javascript can redirect address that you're actually browsing. When it happens native callback `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` is called with special command-containing URL. This URL is passed from javascript and then you can parse this URL in your callback and invoke appropriate action.

Generally speaking you can make your own JSBridge functionality, it should work like this:

1. In your javascript when you want to perform any command, invoke:

   window.location.href= "command://goToHomeViewController"
2. In your delegate of  webView which loaded that page with this javaScript you make a hook for your command.

In your ViewController.m

```
(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)p_WebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request         navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType  
{

    BOOL result = YES;
    NSString *urlString = [[request URL] absoluteURL];
    if ([urlString compare:@"command://goToHomeViewController"] == NSOrderedSame) 
    {
        result = NO;
        [self goToHomeViewController];
    }

    return result;    
}
```

This way you got the command intercepted in your shouldStartLoadWithRequest, then you perform the command in your ViewController native code and return NO that webView cancels loading page.

Comment: Thank you, but I am not sure this is exactly what I am looking for. Also, I tried to download and run the JSBridge example, and they talk about I need the JSON Framework, and they say it is included, but it's not. I cannot find the framework to install.  I don't want to jump back to a UIWebView, I need to jump back from the Javascript   to a standard UIViewController. Do you know if this is possible?  Thanks Again.

Comment: You need to intercept incoming URL and turn it into a command as shown above.

Comment: I think I am on the right track here, and thanking you for your help. The only think now is to track down in the code where to place the above code. In the MainViewController the shouldStartLoadWithRequest is commented out. The app is using Cordova (aka PhoneGap) and it has ChildBrowser and ASIHTTPRequest. I  have been tasked to add a jump to a new UIViewController. If you have any other ideas, they would be greatly appreciated. Thanks Again!

Comment: I havent use ASIHTTPRequest but I would try to intercept the URL in my delegate with: - (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request willRedirectToURL:(NSURL *)newURL; or - (void)requestStarted:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request;